# Change HTML element and restore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website with 2 links.

Once a user clicks a link, this has to become a h2 title without a link.
When the user clicks on the second link, the first links must be restored to its previous state and the second link should become a h2 element.

The links have the purpose of showing a new tab, so they do not reload the page.

**HTML** (don't mind the href link)

```
<div id="Panel" class="header-panels">
    <a data-linked="#panelImages" href=".../images/#" tabindex="0" class="active">Foto's</a>
    <a data-linked="#panelVideos" href=".../videos/#" tabindex="0">Video's</a>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to do this with javascript/jquery?

I have tried stuff like:

```
var p = $('.header-panels .active');
var a = $('<h2></h2>').append(p.contents());
p.replaceWith(a);
```

And it works to change the a tag into h2, but I cannot seem to recreate the a tag with all the attributes when a users clicks a second time.

Or does anyone know a better approach on this?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: Is it a requirement to make it an `<h2>` tag if not jQuery has two functions, addClass() & removeClass() which works very nice.

Comment: What about using a show/hide features on the element so that toggling the link hides the <a> and shows the <h2> and viceversa?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, H2 however is a must. The show/hide idea sounds like an interesting approach. I'll have a look at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/F4Vkv/)

```
var all_a = $('#Panel a'); //cache your selector
var h2 = $('<h2/>').attr('id', 'temp');//created a h2 tag with id temp (just for identification if u need to style it)
all_a.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();//stop default behavior of click if u want
    all_a.show(); //show all a tag inside id Panel
    var $this = $(this); //cache selectore
    h2.text($this.text()).insertBefore($this); //insert h2 before current a tag clicked  and with it's text
    $this.hide(); //hide clicked a
});
```

[.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use separate elements and hide/show them as required? E.g.

```
<div id="Panel" class="header-panels">
  <a data-linked="#panelImages" href=".../images/#" tabindex="0" class="active"     id="fotolink">Foto's</a><h2 id="foto" style="display: none;">Foto's</h2>
  <a data-linked="#panelVideos" href=".../videos/#" tabindex="0"     id="videolink">Video's</a><h2 id="video" style="display: none;">Video's</h2>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#fotolink").on("click", function (e) {
    $("#fotolink").hide();
    $("#foto").show();
    $("#videolink").show();
    $("#video").hide();
    //e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("#videolink").on("click", function (e) {
    $("#fotolink").show();
    $("#foto").hide();
    $("#videolink").hide();
    $("#video").show();
    //e.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

In light of your comment, I would then store the reference to the old anchor element and use `detach()`. E.g.

```
  var oldLink;
  function removeH2() {
    var h2 = $("#textheading");
    if(h2) {
      $(oldLink).insertBefore(h2);
      $(h2).remove();
    }
  }
  function toText(a) {
    oldLink = a;
    var h2 = $('<h2 id="textheading">' + $(a).text() + '</h2>');
    $(h2).insertAfter(a);
    $(a).detach();
  }
  $("#fotolink").on("click", function (e) {
      //e.preventDefault();
      removeH2();
      toText(e.target);
  });
  $("#videolink").on("click", function (e) {
      //e.preventDefault();
      removeH2();
      toText(e.target);
  });
```

Comment: Seperation of elements is an option, however the HTML is dynamically generated in C#. Thats why I would like a solution to change it with javascript/jquery without touching the HTML. But it is a good backup solution.

Answer (score 0):

This script let you toggle 'h2' and 'a' without adding third element, it just replace 'h2' with a 'a' element, and add all the parameters of 'a' element to the 'h2' element on the form of data.

```
$(document).on('click', '#Panel a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);

    var $h2Elem = $this.parents('#Panel').find('h2');
    console.log($h2Elem);
    $h2Elem.each(function (index, item) {
        var linked = $(item).data('linked'),
            href = $(item).data('href'),
            tabindex = $(item).data('tabindex'),
            text = $(item).text();
        $(item).replaceWith('<a data-liked="' + linked + '" href="' + href + '" tabindex="' + tabindex + '">' + text + '<a>');
    });

    var linked = $(this).data('linked'),
        href = $(this).attr('href'),
        tabindex = $(this).attr('tabindex'),
        text = $(this).text();
    $this.replaceWith('<h2 data-liked="' + linked + '" data-href="' + href + '" data-tabindex="' + tabindex + '">' + text + '<h2>');
});
```

Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/prakashapkota/Kgtae/)

Comment: Thanks for helping. This code seems to work but when you inspect element it generates a lot of useless html when you click a couple of times. So it is not really optimal.